# macOS Android Studio for M1 chip crashing immediately

Tags: macos, android-studio, apple-m1

All I've done is unpack the zip, and when I try to open Android Studio, it crashes immediately. I see the icon in the dock for two seconds tops, before it crashes.

I also tried using the latest Canary build and have the same results.
I checked and apparently JDK comes bundled with it, so I don't need that installed in advance.

Am definitely using the M1 / ARM build for macOS running macOS Monterey Beta.

The traceback error is incredibly long and I am unable to pin where the issue lies, and I'm not sure that I should really post the entire thing. Where I am confused is that this is a relatively new Macbook Air on the M1 chip with hardly anything installed on it, so I don't understand what the conflict is or where to begin here...

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by upgrading to the latest beta.